How to modify multiple outbound/external HTTP requests for NestJS
I have a NestJS app that acts as a central point for communicating with several different APIs. Each one will require different token authentication in the headers, so I want to have a custom HttpService for each one depending on which API I need to interact with.
What I've done so far is to make a service that extends the HttpService and will modify the headers for outgoing HTTP requests.
@Injectable()
export class SharepointHttpService extends HttpService implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {
    super();
  }

  public onModuleInit(): void {
    this.httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
      config.headers.Authorization = `My-Token-Here`;
      return config;
    });
}

I made an ApiModule that will contain all my specialized HTTP Services
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: SharepointHttpService, useExisting: HttpService },
    { provide: OtherHttpService, useExisting: HttpService },
  ],
  exports: [SharepointHttpService, OtherHttpService],
})
export class ApiModule {}

In a different module where I want to call the API I import them like this
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule, ApiModule],
  controllers: [ExampleController],
  providers: [ExampleService, SharepointHttpService, OtherHttpService],
})
export class ExampleModule {}

And from there I would hope to just inject them like this and it would handle everything.
@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
  constructor(private readonly spHttpService: SharepointHttpService) {}

  getThing() {
    return this.spHttpService.get('some-endpoint');
  }
}

But what I get is this error
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SharepointHttpService (?, HttpService). Please make sure that the argument "AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN" at index [0] is available in the ApiModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is ApiModule a valid NestJS module?
- If "AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN" is a provider, is it part of the current ApiModule?
- If "AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN" is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ApiModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing "AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN" */ ]
  })

What am I doing wrong? Is this the best way to approach doing what I am trying to do here?

you can't extends that HttpService class because youn can't access the internal providers that @nestjs/axios has.
In your case, the error is because your SharepointHttpService prover has declared a dependency on a provider that only HttpModule has
Instead, you can enhance the internal axios instance following what I suggested in this article: https://dev.to/micalevisk/nestjs-tip-how-to-inject-multiple-versions-of-the-same-provider-into-one-module-eg-many-axios-instances-5agc
or you can use a factory provider that will create an instance of SharepointHttpService that inherits from HttpService (using some sort of JS prototype trick)

Ha, so that is quite literally the article that started me down this path! So I feel a little lost on exactly what I need to do next. I need to call 3 different apis all with different interceptors that can’t interfere with each other. I thought that’s what I was attempting to do here

ok, so the key I was missing is that I need to do HttpService.register({}) for each module. Only doing it on some and not others caused interference between them. Each module will now have it's own instance
